# products not showing up in magento frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am facing a problem in magento store, when any new customer group is added by admin site and if it is assigned to customer, for that particular customer no product showing, the page displaying like "There are no products matching the selection."
Please suggest me how this problem can resolved? or why this is arising?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding price index?

Comment: Rebuilding indexes and clearing caches sounds like a good idea. Hopefully there shouldn't be too many customer groups to add so the effort is minimal.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-1-4-no-products-displayed-in-category-listing/ This might be your solution :)

Comment: possible solution here: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-1-4-no-products-displayed-in-category-listing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I got by

**click on promotion->catalog price rule->apply rule**

This is some how related with Indexing. and group or any rule created on that group will get apply on front end successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. I got my imported products shown up by disabling all and then enabling all again.

http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/